# android how can i use ObjectAnimator class for android 2.2

Tags: android, android-animation, android-2.2-froyo, android-library

I want to use ObjectAnimator class animations to my android 2.2 project. I have tried using support package 4 and it  deosn't work. Is there any way that i can import this class and related files to my project or Any external library for such animations ?

Answer (score 5):

This guy made a great package of `Property Animation` framework for *Android < 3.0* , check out [here](http://nineoldandroids.com/)